# Chrome debugger in Visual Studio Code gets stuck

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code

If I try to start debugging in Visual Studio Code, I get the following error:

[image]

No matter what launch.json I use I always get this error. Tried a lot of launch.json configuration. Don't know why it tries to load `localhost:9876/debug.html` when I set the url to localhost:8100.

My app is running on 8100 port. Debugger for Chrome is plugin is installed. How could I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was quite easy. For a long time I did not make a restart to my computer. After a computer restart the debug is working now.